# How to hide or inhibit prev/next navigation in reveal.js

Tags: controls, hide, reveal.js

I have a presentation that goes down some slides and i want to hide or inhibit prev/next navigation just on the bottom slides.
I mean, i dont want the users can go left or right when they are in the bottom slides.

There is some code like "<section data-controls="hide>" or how can i do it?

thanks